# pip installation failure of pyAV with exit status 1181

Tags: python, visual-studio, ffmpeg, pip, pyav

I am having trouble installing PyAV through pip. First it required me to download Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools

```
building 'av.buffer' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

and when I did install this, I get the following error

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'avcodec.lib'
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\Kesar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
```

I even tried to build PyAV from source, but the same problem persists. How do I solve this?

Comment: Have you installed/built the FFmpeg libraries on your system?

Comment: Form the [Installation instructions](https://github.com/mikeboers/PyAV#installation): "If you want to use your **existing FFmpeg/Libav**" (emphasize mine — phd).

Comment: The pip installation of ffmpeg was done successfully @slhck. The conda installation can be done, but I need it in Python27.

Comment: What is a "pip installation of ffmpeg"? ffmpeg's libraries have to be installed via their own source code. Also I'd strongly recommend using Python 3.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I built the ffmpeg library on my system. Using Python 3 now. All the [dependencies](https://docs.mikeboers.com/pyav/develop/installation.html#dependencies) exist, except for maybe pkg-config maybe. But when I try to pip install PyAV, I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with the method by copy the lib files into the python "libs" directory and the include directories into the "includes" directory, which can also be seen in [this site](https://github.com/mikeboers/PyAV/issues/467)